# make difference between 2 buttons

Tags: html, jsp, servlets

In my JSP i have 2 buttons submit one for updating and the other is for deleting from database.
I put i button like the following:

```
<td><img src="ok.jpg"  onclick="MettreAjourForm();" name="ok"/></td>
```

and in the same servlet i want to make difference in the treatement of the 2 cases.
Is there any proposition?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just give the buttons a name and value as with every other HTML input element. Only the `name=value` pair of the *actually* pressed button will be sent to the server as request parameter. You can then determine the action based on the value:

```
<input type="submit" name="action" value="edit">
<input type="submit" name="action" value="delete">
```

..with the following in the Servlet:

```
String action = request.getParameter("action");

if ("edit".equals(action)) {
    // Edit button was pressed.
} else if ("delete".equals(action)) {
    // Delete button was pressed.
}
```

You can also give the buttons a different name so that you just need to check its presence in the request parameter map:

```
<input type="submit" name="edit" value="edit">
<input type="submit" name="delete" value="delete">
```

..with the following in the Servlet:

```
String edit = request.getParameter("edit");
String delete = request.getParameter("delete");

if (edit != null) {
    // Edit button was pressed.
} else if (delete != null) {
    // Delete button was pressed.
}
```

No need for Javascript hacks/workarounds. It would only make your website unuseable when the client has JS disabled.